# Accessing dynamic databases via spring-data-mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-mongo

I am trying to access data from different databases based on a runtime variable. For this purpose, I have a custom implementation of `MongoOperations`. My implementation is same as `MongoTemplate` except my `getDb()` method looks like below:

```
public DB getDb() {
    return mongoDbFactory.getDb(PropertyManager.getCurrentTenant().getCode());
}
```

While reading data in a transaction, I am getting below error:

```
[TransactionSynchronizationUtils] - TransactionSynchronization.beforeCompletion threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No value for key [Mongo: localhost/127.0.0.1:27017] bound to thread
```

It appears harmless as this exception is only logged:

```
public static void triggerBeforeCompletion() {
    for (TransactionSynchronization synchronization : TransactionSynchronizationManager.getSynchronizations()) {
        try {
            synchronization.beforeCompletion();
        }
        catch (Throwable tsex) {
            logger.error("TransactionSynchronization.beforeCompletion threw exception", tsex);
        }
    }
}
```

But I am having a hard time figuring out why this is happening. Any clues?

Versions:

- spring-data-mongodb: 1.2.3.RELEASE
- spring-tx: 4.0.5.RELEASE

There was a [bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-546) raised for similar issue which was fixed in `1.1 GA` release.

Answer (score 0):

It worked by extending

- `SimpleMongoDbFactory`: returning custom DB in `DB getDb(String dbName)`.
- `MongoTemplate`: Supplying above factory.